# fadeOut and then change image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a question about the `.attr` jQuery method.
I want to create 4 event on click: fade Out, delay, change src attribute and the fade in.
I have this code:

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {   
    $('img').fadeOut().delay(800).attr('src','1-big.jpg').fadeIn();      
});
```

But when I click the button the image changes immediately and then it fades out, delay and fadein. Why the .attr method run first?

Answer (score 4):

Use callbacks to help enforce the order that the functions run -

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() { 
    $('img').fadeOut(800, function() {
        $(this).attr('src','1-big.jpg').fadeIn();      
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The delay function can only be used to delay jQuery effects, or perhaps more accurately, functions that use an effects queue. Changing of the src attribute will therefore happen immediately.

In this case, you can run a function after the fadeOut has finished with a callback, change the src attribute, and then delay before fading in:

```
// default fadeOut time is 400ms, which now needs to be included
$('img').fadeOut(400, function() {
    $(this).attr('src','1-big.jpg').delay(800).fadeIn();
});
```

It may also be a good idea to pre-load the image, just in case it cannot be downloaded within 800 milliseconds.

Comment: Aren't fadeOut() and fadeIn() animation that delay() can act on? I'm pretty sure that these are placed in the queue.

Comment: Wait, nevermind, the attr() is not part of the queud elements *smacks forhead as I was typing*. I was doing a little too much thinking without really thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use animation callbacks:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  $('img').fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', '1-big.jpg');
    $(this).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Maybe worth considering DeSandro's imagesLoaded plugin: https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded